# Entity Set Name Changing Randomly

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a local and development environment, each very similar to each other (OS differences aside).  They both run the same project which is making use of the Entity Framework.  I use LINQpad quite a bit to interrogate data on both environments -- but where required I have access to SQL etc. etc.

So, this is all started with a very strange occurance.  Within my business logic layer, I make a call to get a list of `Contacts` and then marshall that list into a custom type. The custom-type calls for an `Initial` index based on the name of each of the contacts.

For reference, this is the code that performs the marshalling:-

```
private static IEnumerable<AlphabetisedContact> _getGroupedContacts(int clientid)
        {
            return _getLiteContacts(clientid).GroupBy(c => c.Name[0]).Select(
                    g => new AlphabetisedContact { Initial = g.Key, Contacts = g.ToList() }).OrderBy(g => g.Initial);
        }
```

So, this all seems to work fine. Except, it never returns any `Contact` with the first initial of `a`. I decided to try and debug this and using LINQpad found a weirdness.  Whether this has anything to do with my code not returning `a` contacts I don't know (??), but this was the weirdness I found:-

Local Machine:-
[image]

Development Machine:-
[image]

For the less eagle-eyed of you, the Entity Set Name returned by EF, seems to be different.  With the development machine, they're returned with underscores between words -- which is not how the EDMX was setup.  For example, it is **Name** on local, **Contact_name** on dev.  Again, this may have **absolutely nothing** to do with why I can't get `a` contacts. I don't get errors on the dev box, contacts are returned etc. etc. but I can't get `a` contacts.

Can anyone offer some assistance/advice/guidance on how to fix this? It's become a case of "wood-for-the-trees" now...

Help appreciated.

Comment: On the development machine you connect to the database, not an EF context.

Comment: @GertArnold, thanks! However, that still leaves the main quandary ... why do I not get `a` contacts in the return?

Comment: Sure, but that's the subject of your later question. I've taken a look at it and it doesn't seem to make any sense. Really weird.

Comment: @GertArnold thanks for taking a look Gert, appreciated.  Turned out that it was impossible for any of you to answer - see later question. Thanks for taking the time. +1.

Comment: Haha! How reassuring. I'm not alone....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was a catastrophic boo-boo on my part. Please see answer to this on this SO:

[Why Won't This LINQ Return A Particular Initial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14675814/why-wont-this-linq-return-a-particular-initial#comment20528102_14675814)

Thanks to all who took the time to take a peek - and at least a stab at answer.

;)