# Why Won't This LINQ Return A Particular Initial?

Tags: linq

I have the following LINQ:-

```
private static IEnumerable<AlphabetisedContact> _getGroupedContacts(int clientid)
{
  return _getLiteContacts(clientid).GroupBy(c => c.Name[0]).Select(
  g => new AlphabetisedContact { Initial = g.Key, Contacts = g.ToList() }).OrderBy(g => g.Initial);  }
```

Which returns all contacts except any with the letter `a`? Am I missing something?

**edit** Currently it returns something like this:-

```
    [{
        "$id": "1",
        "Initial": "B",
        "Contacts": [{
            "$id": "2",
            "ContactId": 12,
            "Name": "Bryan Chiney",
            "PrimaryContact": {
                "$id": "3",
                "Type": "Email",
                "Value": "bazrith@hotmail.com"
            },
            "Avatar": "/images/avatars/default.jpg",
            "UserId": null
        }, {
            "$id": "4",
            "ContactId": 22,
            "Name": "Bryan Billbags",
            "PrimaryContact": {
                "$id": "5",
                "Type": "Email",
                "Value": "bryan@atomic.com"
            },
            "Avatar": "/images/avatars/contacts/randomiser/1.jpg",
            "UserId": 15
        },
...
```

I would expect the first `Initial` block to include my number of `A` contacts...  If I add a new contact with the name `Bryn McWinkawonk` for instance, he'll appear, but `Alice Alikemen` doesn't...?

**edit** `_getLiteContacts()` call accesses the database with the passed param:-

```
private static IEnumerable<LiteContact> _getLiteContacts(int clientid)
        {
            return _getContacts(clientid).Select(c => new LiteContact()
                    { ContactId = c.ContactId, ContactType = Enum.GetName(typeof (ContactTypeObject.Type), c.Type), Name = c.Name, PrimaryContact = _marshallFirstContactDetail(c.ContactId), 
                        Avatar = c.Avatar, UserId = c.UserId }).ToList();
        }
```

`_getContacts()`:-

```
private static IEnumerable<Contact> _getContacts(int clientid)
        {
            using (var ctx = new atomicEntities())
            {
                var contacts = from c in ctx.Contacts
                               where c.ClientId == clientid
                               select c;
                return contacts.ToList();
            }
        }
```

`_marshallFirstContactDetail()`:-

```
private static Model.Contact.ContactDetail _marshallFirstContactDetail(int contact)
        {
            return _marshallContactDetails(contact).FirstOrDefault();
        }
```

`_marshallContactDetails()`:-

```
private static IEnumerable<Model.Contact.ContactDetail> _marshallContactDetails(int contact)
        {
            using (var ctx = new atomicEntities())
            {
                var o = from d in ctx.ContactDetails
                        join cd in ctx.ContactDetailTypes on d.ContactDetailTypeId equals cd.ContactDetailTypeId
                        where d.ContactId == contact
                        select new Model.Contact.ContactDetail {Type = cd.Description, Value = d.Description};
                return o.ToList();
            } 
        }
```

**example data**

```
contact_id  client_id   contact_name    contact_type
8   22  Cain Allan  2
9   23  Bazrith Banners 2
10  22  Spencer Grep    1
12  22  Bryan Chiney    1
13  22  Dave Carter 4
15  22  Steve Tite  8
16  22  Henry Laythorpe 8
17  22  Chris Barker    8
18  22  Simon Cox   2
19  22  Russell Jacobs  1
20  22  John Wyndham    2
21  22  Isabel March    5
22  22  Bryan Billbags  2
23  22  Stu Plum    2
24  22  Pete Sorensen   7
25  22  Tom Francis 1
26  22  Rich McCormick  1
27  22  Tim Cain    4
28  22  Alex Ray-Harvey 1
29  22  Ryan Bennett    1
30  22  Alice Griswald  3
31  22  Archibald Smyth 3
32  22  Benjamin Franklin   5
```

Help appreciated.

Comment: that should do it provided you have any contacts that start with `a` - care to add sample data and expected output?

Comment: @BrokenGlass updated as requested ;)

Comment: Need sample input as well - your code should work. Also you are only showing the JSON output - your problem might also be in the conversion from C# to JSON. Did you go through line by line to see where your data "disappears" ?

Comment: A `public` method accesses this `private`, with the public being called directly by the WebAPI.  `AlphabetisedContact` is simply a char and List of custom objects.  I will edit to show results of `_getLiteContacts()` call/input.

Comment: Tested the linq part (with just string list and an anonymous type) and it's working fine...

Comment: Yep. Exactly. Working fine for me too - yet for some utterly bizarre reason, my `a` contacts never make an appearance! I'm try to investigate further...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. Firstly, a big apology to whomever took the time to look at this question. Turns out the problem was in the layer above this where some paging took place. A piece of LINQ was run on the result of the `GetGroupedContacts` (=> `_getGroupedContacts()`) like so:-

`GetGroupedContacts().Take(1000).Skip(1)`

This naturally, always skipped the first result.

Complete **spanner** dooburt signing off!